# How to position elements in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dashboard with the adminlte template and I cannot get the result I expect, my page is shown as follows. enter the description of the image here

I want the web to occupy the width of the browser and there are no spaces left, but for some reason I can't get the result. (The red squares indicate the space I want to eliminate)

[Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLi9f.png)

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>AdminLTE 3 | Dashboard</title>
   </head>
   <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
      <div class="wrapper">
         <headerprincipal></headerprincipal>
         <!-- /.navbar -->
         <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
         <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <menuprincipal></menuprincipal>
         </aside>
         <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
         <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <div class="content-header">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row mb-2">
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0">Dashboard</h1>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.col -->
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                           <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                           <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard v1</li>
                        </ol>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.col -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.row -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.content-header -->
            <!-- Main content -->
            <div class="content">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="small-box bg-success">
                           <div class="inner">
                              <p>Eventos</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="icon">
                              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                           </div>
                           <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="small-box bg-info">
                           <div class="inner">
                              <h3>150</h3>
                              <p>New Orders</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="icon">
                              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                           </div>
                           <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                     <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="small-box bg-info">
                           <div class="inner">
                              <h3>150</h3>
                              <p>New Orders</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="icon">
                              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                           </div>
                           <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="small-box bg-info">
                           <div class="inner">
                              <h3>150</h3>
                              <p>New Orders</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="icon">
                              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                           </div>
                           <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.container-fluid -->
         <footermain></footermain>
         <!-- Control Sidebar -->
         <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
            <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
         </aside>
         <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
      </div>
      <!-- ./wrapper -->
   </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help.

Note: I am using angular 12.

angular.json:

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "avcangular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/avcangular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/demo.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "avcangular:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "avcangular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "avcangular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "avcangular"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems these below mentioned classes css might be causing the issue.

hold-transition,sidebar-mini, layout-fixed or wrapper

Check if any of the class has some left and right margin or left and right padding defined. If it's defined try removing it and check the result.